# How to say that you need to do something?

Tags: grammar, word-choice

What's the best way to say that someone needs to do something, as in "5 English slangs you need to know"? I found some ways

> 知る必要があるの5つ英語のスラング。
> 知らないといけないの5つ英語のスラング。
> 知るべきの５つ英語のスラング。

Which is more correct or in what context should each be used? Is there a better way to say this?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, one の is necessary between 五つ and 英語、and the first の is not necessary and the second の can be omitted such as 知る必要がある5つの英語スラング.

知る必要がある is "you need to know".

知らないといけない(知らなければならない) is "you must know".

知るべき is "you should know".

Comment: So, in addition to the difference in meaning, is there also a difference in politeness? Are these sentences polite or casual?

Comment: @Yasushiki  They are normal how to say. If they changed to a polite form such as お知りになる必要がある5つの英語スラング, they would be awkward.